# How to check the state of an input element after adding a required element dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I added to all of the inputs element in a specific state a required field in this way:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // activate required function
        v = data[i].Required;
        if (v)
            document.getElementById(response.data[i].ID).required = true;             
}
```

Now i want to add to each input this code for example:

```
 <span style="color:red" ng-show="addOrEditForm.myPassword.$dirty && addOrEditForm.myPassword.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="addOrEditForm.myPassword.$error.required">Password is required.</span>
 </span>
```

The problem is that this code doesn't work. I can't see the error massage, but if i will add manually to a specific input element the "required" field so this code is working, i can see the error message.

Comment: Why don't you use ng-required on your inputs so the angular validation will work fine ?

Comment: Something like this:  **$("#"+response.data[i].ID).attr("ng-required", true)**;

Comment: In the ng-required, you place a method that check your data array according to the input id...

Comment: You have a angular controller right ? Which version of Angular are you using ?

Comment: Are you using components?

Comment: Can you tell us what data is? is a result of an http call?

Comment: Yes, it holds an object of the id and required field

Answer (score 0):

I have created a jsfiddle example 
http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9176/

I have create a model `user` with every Id of dom and inside it I have added two properties `value` and `required`. I have assigned `value` to `ngModel` for every Id and `required` to `ngRequired` property of input field.

After calling the backend i simple change `required` value for ids that has `data[i].Required` set to true

Answer (score 0):

Better use ng-required.       document.getElementById(response.data[i].ID);
  Instead create
     $scope dynamically.  Like $scope[key] = true; 
 and use it html ng-required as per your need.